# Suppress "unknown enum constant" warning for enums used in class retention annotations

Tags: java, annotations, javac

When I'm compiling a project with a certain external jar dependency, javac is producing the following warning:

```
warning: unknown enum constant ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY
```

This is due to the fact that the external jar dependency uses a class-retention annotation with an enum in its arguments. Something along the lines of this:

```
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.ReferenceCardinality;
public class ExternalJarClass {
    @Reference(cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY)
    public void someMethod(...) {}
}
```

I have found two ways to remove this warning:

1. Including the command-line option `-nowarn`. However, I don't want to disable all warnings when compiling my project.
2. Including the annotation library jar in the classpath.

I can live with option 2, but since my project doesn't require the annotation library, I'm wondering if there is any other way to suppress this warning.

Comment: "*[...] but since my project doesn't require the annotation library, I'm wondering if there is any other way to suppress this warning.*" - You might not use it, but the implementation of your dependency may use it internally. This is most probably why it is set to `RetentionPolicy.CLASS`. Safe bet is to include the annotation library in your classpath.

Comment: In my situation, I'm using a library built with osgi annotations for a non-osgi application. The osgi annotations are only used to generate the osgi-specific meta-inf properties of the external jar itself, but are otherwise not used. I'd preferably not want to include the osgi dependency every time I want to use the external jar.

Comment: Also in this case, javac is generating a warning for not being able to find the enum ReferenceCardinality, but not generating a warning for not being able to find Reference. It seems to me that javac should either generate warnings for both types or for neither.

Comment: Well in this case, someone did not apply the [Interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) (or just did not care). Anyway... you are now stuck with it. Either live with the warning, include the library, compile the part separately with `-nowarn` or rewrite the code :)